# Eclipse won't change output type in C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, dll

I started an Eclipse project as an executable. It worked correctly. Then I changed it to a DLL in `Project Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Build Artifact -> Artifact Type`. It still worked. (this was all with basically Hello World functionality)

So I included a bunch of stuff in my project file to actually move toward the app I want to build. I couldn't get it to quite compile, but I've included a lot of paths and libraries that I don't want to have to re-enter (or I'd just start a new project). Just to find out if I could still compile Hello World with all these includes, I changed it back to an executable in the same spot as above. It seems to work, in that it changes it on that screen; and it even changes the file extension that it feeds to the `/OUT` parameter of the linker. But it's still passing the `/DLL` parameter to the linker, as well, and I can't find the project property page where I can remove this.

Note that, when I copy-paste the command line that the Eclipse console spits out, to the command prompt and remove the `/DLL` parameter manually, it links properly and forms an executable that produces the correct functionality. But when I try to run the exe from the IDE, or whenever it tries to rebuild, it gives me a message box error saying my process has encountered a problem.

```
Error starting process.
Cannot run program "C:\Users\2659\workspace\MoreStuff\Debug\MoreStuff.exe": Launching failed
Cannot run program "C:\Users\2659\workspace\MoreStuff\Debug\MoreStuff.exe": Launching failed
Cannot run program "C:\Users\2659\workspace\MoreStuff\Debug\MoreStuff.exe": Launching failed
```

How can I remove this `/DLL` flag so that I can have actual control over what my project is outputting?

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem: I created a new C++ project with shared artifact nature and wanted to test it by adding a main function and a new executable build option.

In order to successfully change the nature you have also to go to `Project Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> G++ Linker -> Shared Library Settings` and (in the proper configuration) uncheck the `Shared` option.

It worked for me.